# Unable to use Scroll function in Appium

Tags: ios, appium

I was using Appium 0.15 for IOS7. I was trying to use scroll function with the following code

```
final JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        final Map<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
        scrollObject.put("direction", "up");
        System.out.println("Scroll object:"+scrollObject.size());
        jsExecutor.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

But while executing this code I am getting following exception

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'Automation-MAC-2.local', ip: '10.0.25.155', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.4', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: c2b31197-7090-4458-9aca-dea6793ee2c5
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{app=/Users/Wiley/Documents/JASAPPS/JGRD_simulator.app, platform=MAC, javascriptEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, browserName=iOS, webStorageEnabled=false, device=iPhone, locationContextEnabled=false, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=6.1}]
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Update to the latest version of appium 1.2.2 for a wider feature set.

Comment: @Parosh,  above "mobile : scroll"/"mobile : scrollTo" are depreciated , please check this video which show latest appium version 1.5.3 supported command,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're using an old version of appium** *upgrade to the latest version for a larger feature set!*

```
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code. It will work

```
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/select_dialog_listview"));
            HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
            scrollObject.put("text", "The text you need to scroll to");
            scrollObject.put("element",( (RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
            driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```